# How to pass a pointer to a function (and its parameters!) in PHP

Tags: php, function, pointers

After a while, I was finally able to pass a pointer to a function like this:

```
function originalFunction($value) {
  print "I am in the function, with value $value";
}

function testFunctionPointer($functionName, $id) {
  $functionName($id);
}

$test = testFunctionPointer("originalFunction", 200);
```

Basically, I realized that if you pass a STRING and you use that string as a function name, the function is executed.
In fact, in the example above, the "originalFunction" is correctly called.

But how can I get the parameter working? It's always zero...

PS: I know that what I am doing is not clean, it shouldn't be done, etc. etc. etc. But it's just for an INTERNAL PROJECT I am doing for MYSELF, so nobody will get hurt by this ;)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please see http://php.net/call_user_func and read the chapters on [callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is executing well for me, outputting `200` as expected.

Also you can directly call it like this:

```
call_user_func("originalFunction", 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, other than removing the ] and putting } this code worked for me I got I am in the function, with value 200

Im running php 5.4.4

```
<?php 

function originalFunction($value) { 
  print "I am in the function, with value $value"; 
}

function testFunctionPointer($functionName, $id) { 
  $functionName($id); 
} 

$test = testFunctionPointer("originalFunction", 200); 


?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check my PHP version. I got an hint from a guy here but I cannot find the answer anymore. Anyway, he told me to check the "call_user_func" function. The syntax should be call_user_func('functionName', $parameter);

Comment: Depends if there was anything else you wished to do, but, yes, there are other choices, I was just trying to say to you your code should work or at least does for me